# Copy columns from multiple spreadsheets. Data moving up when column empty on spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I have the below code. The code will go into each of the 17 workbooks and extract certain columns based on the columns headers name. This will repeat and add to the bottom of the master workbook, until the last one has been extracted. 
Unfortunately, if there is nothing in one of the columns on one of the individual 17 workbooks, the data from the next workbook gets moved up in the cells. Is there anyway to sort this. I have added the code below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyColumns()
Dim CopyFromPath As String, FileName As String
Dim CopyToWb As Workbook, wb As Workbook, CopyToWs As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, NextRow As Long, lcol As Long, c As Long, sv As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myCol As Long
Dim myHeader As Range
r\"
Set CopyToWb = ActiveWorkbook
Set c).End(xlUp).Row
                    If lastRow = 1 Then GoTo nxt

                    Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(lastRow, c)).Copy
                    CopyToWs.Activate
                    Set myHeader = CopyToWs.Rows(1).Find(What:=.Cells(1, c).Value, Lookat:=xlWhole)
                    With CopyToWs
                        If Not myHeader Is Nothing Then
                            myCol = myHeader.Column
                            NextRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, myCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                            .Cells(NextRow, myCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            Set myHeader = Nothing
                        End If
nxt:
                    End With
                End If
            Next c
    wb.Close saveChanges:=False
    End With
    FileName = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you know the exact part of your code that causes the unwanted behaviour on an empty sheet?

Comment: If I am understanding your problem correctly (that some of the columns you are copying from a worksheet do not have the same number of rows as other columns, but you want everything to continue to line up), you need to move the calculation of `NextRow` outside your `For c` loop, and base it on a single column that you know will always be populated.  Then you should use that same value for all columns until you again calculate `NextRow` when the next workbook is being processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate `NextRow` only once per workbook, and then use it for all columns:

```
Do While Len(FileName) > 0
    'Calculate the next row to be populated for all columns, based on the last
    'used cell in column A
    '(I used column A, but pick whatever destination column will always be
    'populated in every workbook.)
    With CopyToWs
        NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    'Process this workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(CopyFromPath & FileName)
    With wb.Sheets("Open Issue Actions")
        lcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For c = 1 To lcol
            '...
                With CopyToWs
                    If Not myHeader Is Nothing Then
                        myCol = myHeader.Column
                        'NextRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, myCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        .Cells(NextRow, myCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        Set myHeader = Nothing
                    End If
                End With
nxt:
                '...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. If I can quickly just explain. So I have my 17 individual workbooks. I also have my master workbook. The code goes into the folder and extracts the named columns from each individual workbook. However, if one of the columns on the individual workbooks is empty, on the master workbook the data from the next individual workbook moves up into the its position. Does this makes sense and do you think the code above will work. Thank you

Comment: @Tan3157 If you have one column that you know is populated in every workbook, then you can easily find the last used cell in that column (in the destination worksheet) at the start of the processing of each workbook, and then copy all columns from that workbook to that row.  The question is .... do you have such a column?

Comment: @Tan3157 - e.g. Is "Issue Type" always populated for every row in every workbook?  Or is "Issue DocID" always populated?

Comment: @Tan3157 Judging by the image you just posted, it looks like "Issue Type" (column A) will always exist in every row in every workbook.  Therefore the code above will work out which is the next empty cell in column A (row 32 in your image) and paste all the columns from the next workbook into their appropriate columns starting at row 32.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you want one row per sheet. Nothing else. Nothing more. You do not even need to calculate it. You need to increment it `lngRow = lngRow+1`.
Try to use the following into your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColumns()

    Dim lngRow  As Long: lngRow = 1

    Do While Len(FileName) > 0
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(CopyFromPath & FileName)
        With wb.Sheets("Open Issue Actions")
            lngRow = lngRow + 1

            With CopyToWs
                If Not myHeader Is Nothing Then
                    myCol = myHeader.Column
                    .Cells(lngRow, myCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Set myHeader = Nothing
                End If
            End With
        End With
        wb.Close saveChanges:=False
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

In the code you add/edit three things:

- `The line Dim lngRow as Long: lngRow=1` on top with the other `Dim`
- `lngRow = lngRow + 1` after the `With wb.Sheets("Open Issue Actions")`
- the paste values should be like this `.Cells(lngRow, myCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

The whole code is here: https://pastebin.com/kXdzkGZ1

The idea is to have lngRow and to increment it for every WorkSheet that you open. And do not do anything else with it.

In general, your code can be optimized in some ways, if it works ok after the change, put it here for further ideas: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As `NextRow` is only used inside the `If`, it won't matter if it is only calculated within the `If`.

Comment: @vityata - is that an empty header on one of the 17 spreadsheets? Thanks

Comment: @Tan3157 - yup, that's the question. :) And see the edit.

Comment: @vityata - It still doesn't work unfortunately with the same error. The header is on all the spreadsheets. However, if the column is blank or empty the data from the next spreadsheet moves the data into the blank cells. Not sure how to explain without attaching the docs. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @Tan3157 what exactly it moves? The whole column? E.g., put two screenshots with `FAKE DATA` to your question, titled as `Expected` and `Current situation`.

Comment: @Tan3157 Are you trying to ensure that all columns copied from a workbook start at the same destination row, even if some of the columns in the previous workbook were empty?

Comment: @YowE3K - All the columns mentioned on the code will always be on every tracker. I have attached the image to the orginal questions. Thanks again

Comment: @vityata i have attached an image to the original question. I believe it is a link. Thanks for your help

Comment: @vityata Thanks. As I am literally a beginner on VBA where would I add the new code or embed it to my code for it to work effectively? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Vityata - I have just given the code a go. Unfortunately it is not copying everything from each workbook across. Do you know why? Thank you

Comment: @Tan3157 - did you make only these 3 changes? Nothing else?

Comment: @vityata - i also removed the below code.  NextRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, myCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1